# Automatic restart of ip-phones via ssh and cron (sshpass, expect or other solutions)

Tags: ssh, cron, expect, sshpass

The task is to remotely reboot ip-phones every night.
**sshpass:**
`sshpass -p 12345678 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.2.1 reboot`
In response: *Connection to 192.168.2.1 closed by remote host.*
In addition, the phone, as usual in CLI, asks to answer **y**.

**expect:**

```
COMM="
log_file debug.log
exp_internal 1
set timeout 5
spawn ssh admin@192.168.2.1
expect \"password:\"
send \"12345678\r\"
sleep 5
expect \"*>\"
send \"reboot\r\"
sleep 5
expect \"*y/N*\"
send \"y\r\"
expect eof
"
expect -c "$COMM"
```

When I do it myself from the console, everything is ok. Using **cron**, in debug.log, for some reason, after authorization on the device, the line for entering the `expect \"*>\"` command does not appear. Even if we remove `expect \"*>\"` and just use **send**, there is no reaction.
I ask for hints in solving the problem or suggest another solution. Thanks.

different **debug.log** between console and cron
**console**:

```
expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*>"? no
^[[1;36m

expect: does " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\t" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*>"? no
Grandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017
                Grandstream Networks, Inc.
^[[0m
GXV3240>
expect: does " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\tGrandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017\r\n\t\tGrandstream Networks, Inc.\r\n\u001b[0m\r\nGXV3240> " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*>"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\tGrandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017\r\n\t\tGrandstream Networks, Inc.\r\n\u001b[0m\r\nGXV3240>"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\tGrandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017\r\n\t\tGrandstream Networks, Inc.\r\n\u001b[0m\r\nGXV3240>"
send: sending "reboot\r" to { exp5 }
```

**cron:**

```
expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? no

^[[1;36m
        Grandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017
                Grandstream Networks, Inc.
^[[0m
^[[6n
expect: does " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\tGrandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017\r\n\t\tGrandstream Networks, Inc.\r\n\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[6n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "reboot\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " \r\n\u001b[1;36m\r\n\tGrandstream GXV3240 Command-Line Interface Copyright 2017\r\n\t\tGrandstream Networks, Inc.\r\n\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[6n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*y/N*"? no
expect: timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem: without seeing the debug output it's impossible to say.

When you're embedding expect code into a shell script, I recommend using a heredoc -- that makes the quoting much simpler

```sh
expect <<'END_EXPECT'

    log_file debug.log
    exp_internal 1
    set timeout 10
    spawn ssh admin@192.168.2.1
    expect "password:"
    send "12345678\r"
    expect "*>"
    send "reboot\r"
    expect "y/N"
    send "y\r"
    expect eof

END_EXPECT
```

I increased the timeout and removed the sleeps -- generally sleep is not required in an expect script if you have the patterns right.

Comment: I see that from cron, you never get the prompt. Try using `ssh -t` to force a tty.

Comment: Not work. For the test, I wrote a script for SecureCRT on the VBS, and it worked fine in the task scheduler. It's sad that I might have to use this software. Maybe there are other ways in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot Grandstream VoIP terminal – script solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_adr="192.168.0.2"
pass="admin"
sshpass -p ${pass} ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@${ip_adr} << EOF
reboot
exit
EOF
unset pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).